# Word 2011: In track changes mode "final showing markup", most text missing in some table rows

Tags: ms-office

I'm using track changes to edit a large table (several columns, many rows spanning multiple pages). Some columns have only one or a few words, while others have two or three paragraphs of one to three sentences each.

The problem I'm having is that with track changes turned on in "final showing markup" mode, there are several table rows in which only the last word in the last paragraph is actually displayed (this is true whether there's only one word, several words, or one or more paragraphs in a given cell). The displayed text is in the right physical location, but the rest of each cell's area is blank. This problem seems to happen only in table rows that have been heavily edited and only in some but not all heavily edited rows.

Does anyone have an idea of why this occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: What does it look like when you select "final" instead of "Final showing markup"?

Comment: It looks exactly like it should. The problem only occurs in "final showing markup" (and in "original showing markup" for that matter, but I rarely use that mode).